# LaTeX for Microsoft Surface

Tags: miktex, windows, tablet

I have my new Microsoft Surface and I was wondering whether it's possible to install pieces of software like MikTeX and TexMaker on this tablet. Does anyone know?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: @minidiable, rember to accept the the solution offered in the answer to your questions if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have the Surface Pro, you can install [MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/) or [TeX Live](http://tug.org/texlive/) as per any other Windows computer. If you have the Surface RT, there is no precompiled TeX distribution available for ARM processors yet. If you'd like to try building TeX Live for ARM, you can check the [build procedure](http://tug.org/texlive/build.html).

Comment: Just curious to know any experiences you wish to share on installation and aftermath

Comment: I haven't tried building TeX Live; the word `try' in the mention of building it for ARM is quite important!

Answer (score 4):

you can install texmaker on surfacepro tablets but, at least with the surfacepro4 the resolution of the screen will make the UI almost un-usable due to the high resolution of the screen.. the icons and all the menu-tabs are too small...

update: I tried using 1600x1200 instead of 2736x1824 (default surface pro 4 resolution) but still is horrible.. have a look at this picture. You can resize the setting window, but not the buttons on the UI

[image: texmaker with surface pro 4]

Comment: Can you fix that by scaling the display? Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: I just put a new answer to add an image, please have a look. bye

Comment: ok, just edited the original post instead of creating a new answer. thx to Null