# TeX Live on Nokia Lumia 2520 Tablet computer with ARM architecture

Tags: texlive, windows, tablet

Is there precompiled TeX Live system for ARM architecture based Nokia Lumia 2520 tablet with Windows RT 8.1?

Comment: No, there is not, and as it is not a popular system, not even close, I doubt there will be in the near future

Comment: You might have better luck generalizing this to 'Windows over ARM'—it shouldn't matter what device you're using.

Comment: Assuming that the Windows App store has similar licensing limitations to Apple's you can't put a GPL system into it --- the iPad TeX apps have to limit themselves to a BSD-licensed sub-system such as Kergis TeX.

Comment: related? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115714/latex-for-microsoft-surface Anyway, what is this Windows thing? `:P`