# LaTeX for surface 3

Tags: miktex, windows

I am planning to get a Microsoft surface 3. I am wondering that can I download MikTeX and TeXstudio or other LaTeX softwares. I found a same question at this post [LaTeX for Microsoft Surface](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115714/latex-for-microsoft-surface). But this post is before Surface 3 release.

Thanks

Comment: Although the question is old, the answer remains the same. Any x86 or x64 (in other words, Intel or AMD) processor will work; any ARM processor will not work. I am very confused by MS naming conventions for their tablets these days, so I cannot say which version the Surface 3 has...

Comment: @darthbith As I read from Wikipedia, it says that surface 3 utilizes an x86 Intel Atom system-on-chip architecture

Comment: As far as I can see the surface 3 has a standard windows 8.1 as OS. So I see no reason why texlive or miktex shouldn't work (they will work on windows 10 too).